# Unable to Build my workspace due to errors in building industrial core (Required for Kuka Arm for Ubuntu 20.04.02-Noetic)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this link to install kuka_experimental
http://wiki.ros.org/kuka_experimental
It didn't satisfy all the dependencies and gave this error that industrial_robot_client package was missing.

I installed Industrial Core from source using this link.
https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core.git

When i ran this:

```
# checking dependencies
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
```

I got an error that a dependency orocos_kdl package is missing.

I installed it from https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics.git

Based on the error i setup a path for the packages to access python2 for building, referring this.
https://www.fosslinux.com/39384/switching-between-python-2-and-3-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm

This resolved and build most of the packages but there are some errors that persisted.
I have added my error message which i got during catkin build.

```
Errors     << python_orocos_kdl:cmake /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/logs/python_orocos_kdl/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Error at /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl/CMakeLists.txt:41 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl/pybind11

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl/CMakeLists.txt:42 (pybind11_add_module):
  Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".


cd /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/build/python_orocos_kdl; catkin build --get-env python_orocos_kdl | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/src/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/devel/.private/python_orocos_kdl -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/install; cd -
.......................................................................................................
Failed     << python_orocos_kdl:cmake                      [ Exited with code 1 ]                      
Failed    <<< python_orocos_kdl                            [ 2.1 seconds ]                             
Abandoned <<< industrial_core                              [ Unrelated job failed ]                    
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << industrial_trajectory_filters:make /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/logs/industrial_trajectory_filters/build.make.004.log
In file included from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp:45,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/class_loader/class_loader.hpp:46,
                 from /home/rbc-server-101/catkin_ws/src/industrial_core/industrial_trajectory_filters/src/add_smoothing_filter.cpp:38:

Failed     << industrial_trajectory_filters:make           [ Exited with code 2 ]                      
Failed    <<< industrial_trajectory_filters                [ 5.7 seconds ]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373484/unable-to-build-my-workspace-due-to-errors-in-building-industrial-core-(required-for-kuka-arm-for-ubuntu-20.04.02-noetic)?/) by [niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71602/niranjan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had to add an empty virtual function in two files.
Follow this discussion-
https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/pull/244

---

Originally posted by [niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71602/niranjan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0